# Using a UserControl to Login and then enable menuStrip in Primary form

Tags: winforms, user-controls, splitcontainer

Ok so here is what i am trying to do.
I have a Primary form in a C# desktop application in which i have a menuStrip and a splitContainer.
On running the application, I am loading a UserControl named 'Login' to the splitContainer.Panel2 while hiding the menuStrip. The Login control contains fields for Username, Password and a button to log in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jcnK.png

Once authenticated (on click of the button) i want to enable the menuStrip and allow other UserControls in the splitContainer.Panel2, while hiding the Login control.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwLvP.png

How to i achieve this? I was trying to fire up an event from Login control and somehow make it work in Primary form but unable to implement.
Is this approach even worth trying or should i open multiple forms separately (i would hate to do so!)
Any cleaner approach on how to change views in splitContainer.Panel2 (other than stacking panels one above the other, which would be a design nightmare for me) while keeping splitContainer.Panel1 with same content.

Comment: An event would be perfect.  The form would subscribe to the UserControl event and then toggle the controls appropriately.  What difficulty are you having with the event approach?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks for the advice. IDK, events are just not working. Maybe i'm not doing it right, since I referred a few tutorials to do it.

Inside the Login control class I declare:
 
public delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
public event EventHandler Authenticated;

On Login button click:
if user is authenticated from db i do:
1. Authenticated(this, new System.EventArgs());
OR
2. this.Authenticated(this, e);

On the Primary form class i TRY TO do :
Login.EventHandler = new EventHandler(Authenticated);


Flummoxed since its supposed to work according to the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt sounds like it should have worked.

Are you adding the Login control at design-time or via code?

Here's an example of it being created thru code...worked fine for me.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuStrip1.Visible = false;
        Login login = new Login();
        login.Authenticated += new EventHandler(login_Authenticated);
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(login);
    }

    void login_Authenticated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login login = (Login)sender;
        // ... possibly extract some info from "login" ...

        menuStrip1.Visible = true;
        login.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Login UserControl:

```
public partial class Login : UserControl
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler Authenticated;   

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (true) // if they have authenticated
        {
            if (Authenticated != null) // only raise the event if we have subscribers
            {
                Authenticated(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```